# How to find critical point of t distribution when 1-α can't be determine directly from the table.

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, anova

I was following a tutorial on Bonferroni's method. As a challenge I was ask to
Compute the Bonferroni simultaneous confidence interval For a 95 % overall confidence coefficient using the Bonferroni method, the t value is $t_{1-0.05/(2\cdot2), \, 16} = t_{0.9875, \, 16}$

I Can solve these problem but what's really getting be confuse is how they managed to derive 2.473 as the t-value and how I can go about finding a column for 0.9875 (not in my statistic table).
My knowledge about finding critical value from a t distribution
For example, if i want a t*-value for a 90% confidence interval when i have 9 degrees of freedom, go to the bottom of the table, find the column for 90%, and intersect it with the row for df = 9. This gives me a t*–value of 1.833 (rounded).
But how about
$t_{0.9875, \, 16}$ how is it 2.473. I would appreciate your clarification. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where the value you're looking for isn't in a t-table, you can use several different programs to the value you want. For example, in Excel, the formula you're looking for is `T.INV(0.9875,16)`. You could also use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Student%27s+t+distribution+alpha+%3D+0.0125%2C+nu+%3D+16) to calculate the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was quite helpful. Although I was hoping I could do that manually.

Comment: The [CDF of Student's t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) isn't really something you want to have to work with manually, some integrals are just too much of a bother (or impossible) to calculate. It's completely standard to use statistical packages, no statistician or economist ever calculates this type of stuff by hand, so don't feel like you're taking the easy route or anything!